# Xcode 6 "Terminating app due to uncaught exception"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on Xcode 6. I am following a tutorial that explains how to work with tab bar controllers and table views. The first part of the tutorial went fine, then after adding an extra controller and running the app, I get the following error in the console:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'Mrk-WH-vzE-view-zyB-06-j66''

I then created a brand new project adding only the extra controller that gives trouble. The issue persisted. I did some debugging and found that the code crashes when it reaches this specific line:

```
self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
```

In the header file I declared:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;
```

If necessary, I can provide all the code of the .m file.

What is weird is that, in the first project that I was recreating from the tutorial, this piece of code, in a certain class works; when I added a second class and put the same code in it, the app started to crash (it crashes in the second class).

I am not sure if the information provided is sufficient – if not, let me know.

UPDATE:
Ok I have some new info. I decided to prepare the code and post it here. I started commenting things out to see what could be posted and what was irrelevant.
I found out that it was not exactly that line that gives the crash (I used F6 instead of F7). I realized that, after that line, the code goes to another function

```
    - (void)setItems:(NSMutableArray *)items {
if (_items != items) {
    _items = items;

    // Build Shopping List
    [self buildShoppingList];
}}


    - (void)buildShoppingList {
NSMutableArray *buffer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [self.items count]; i++) {
    Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([item inShoppingList]) {
        // Add Item to Buffer
        [buffer addObject:item];
    }
}

// Set Shopping List
self.shoppingList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:buffer];  }


    - (void)setShoppingList:(NSArray *)shoppingList {
if (_shoppingList != shoppingList) {
    _shoppingList = shoppingList;

    // Reload Table View
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}}
```

and the code seems to crash at the line

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

I guess this is a completely different scenario.
The code goes first in setItems and then in the following functions

/// UPDATE 22 December
I can't find a crash log, however this is the stack trace

```
        * thread #1: tid = 0x7e4a, 0x00000001065bbb8a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
        * frame #0: 0x00000001065bbb8a libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
        frame #1: 0x0000000106922e6d CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 205
        frame #2: 0x0000000106fd48c3 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 552
        frame #3: 0x0000000106e33f98 UIKit`-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
        frame #4: 0x0000000106e34588 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadView] + 109
        frame #5: 0x0000000106ff1368 UIKit`-[UITableViewController loadView] + 76
        frame #6: 0x0000000106e347f9 UIKit`-[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
        frame #7: 0x0000000106e34c8e UIKit`-[UIViewController view] + 27
        frame #8: 0x0000000106ff10e3 UIKit`-[UITableViewController tableView] + 30
        frame #9: 0x000000010608caf0 Prova`-[ShoppingListViewController setShoppingList:](self=0x00007fa5c3d32b70, _cmd=0x000000010608d754, shoppingList=0x00007fa5c3f03d90) + 112 at ShoppingListViewController.m:75
        frame #10: 0x000000010608ca50 Prova`-[ShoppingListViewController buildShoppingList](self=0x00007fa5c3d32b70, _cmd=0x000000010608d70c) + 400 at ShoppingListViewController.m:67
        frame #11: 0x000000010608c8a0 Prova`-[ShoppingListViewController setItems:](self=0x00007fa5c3d32b70, _cmd=0x000000010c0eaaea, items=0x00007fa5c3d2fc90) + 112 at ShoppingListViewController.m:51
        frame #12: 0x000000010608cf20 Prova`-[ShoppingListViewController loadItems](self=0x00007fa5c3d32b70, _cmd=0x000000010608d6a8) + 288 at ShoppingListViewController.m:111
        frame #13: 0x000000010608c6fd Prova`-[ShoppingListViewController initWithCoder:](self=0x00007fa5c3d32b70, _cmd=0x00000001087b740f, aDecoder=0x00007fa5c5828600) + 189 at ShoppingListViewController.m:28
        frame #14: 0x0000000106fd59dd UIKit`-[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 205
        frame #15: 0x000000010713a6c6 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
        frame #16: 0x000000010713a895 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1168
        frame #17: 0x000000010713a3fc UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 276
        frame #18: 0x0000000106e317aa UIKit`-[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 927
        frame #19: 0x0000000106e53ec4 UIKit`-[UINavigationController initWithCoder:] + 51
        frame #20: 0x000000010713a6c6 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
        frame #21: 0x000000010713a895 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1168
        frame #22: 0x000000010713a3fc UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 276
        frame #23: 0x0000000106e317aa UIKit`-[UIViewController initWithCoder:] + 927
        frame #24: 0x0000000106e704aa UIKit`-[UITabBarController initWithCoder:] + 51
        frame #25: 0x000000010713a6c6 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
        frame #26: 0x000000010713a3fc UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 276
        frame #27: 0x0000000106fd55d6 UIKit`-[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 153
        frame #28: 0x000000010713a6c6 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 705
        frame #29: 0x000000010713a895 UIKit`UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1168
        frame #30: 0x000000010713a3fc UIKit`-[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 276
        frame #31: 0x0000000106fd4a79 UIKit`-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 990
        frame #32: 0x000000010725e572 UIKit`-[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
        frame #33: 0x0000000106d0eb92 UIKit`-[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 65
        frame #34: 0x0000000106d0dc19 UIKit`-[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1075
        frame #35: 0x0000000106d0cbf2 UIKit`-[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
        frame #36: 0x00000001094de2a3 FrontBoardServices`__31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
        frame #37: 0x000000010685853c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
        frame #38: 0x000000010684e285 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
        frame #39: 0x000000010684e045 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2389
        frame #40: 0x000000010684d486 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
        frame #41: 0x0000000106d0c669 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 413
        frame #42: 0x0000000106d0f420 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1282
        frame #43: 0x000000010608d428 Prova`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff59b73390) + 184 at main.m:15
        frame #44: 0x0000000108eb2145 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

The line

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

corresponds to

```
  frame #9: 0x000000010608caf0 Prova`-[ShoppingListViewController setShoppingList:](self=0x00007fa5c3d32b70, _cmd=0x000000010608d754, shoppingList=0x00007fa5c3f03d90) + 112 at ShoppingListViewController.m:75
```

The table view delegates are

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.shoppingList count];
```

}

the self.shoppingList should be an array with 0 elements. However the code doesn't seem to reach the line

```
 return [self.shoppingList count];
```

as it stops before, at line

```
 [self.tableView reloadData];
```

I also thought that maybe the navigation controller that embeds this crashing class could be responsible, so I removed it and connected the main tab bar controller directly to this item with the custom class, but nothing changed, always the same error

Comment: Hmm. It says that it cannot load a certain NIB (which is a user interface file, typically ending with *.xib). Does your view controller have a corresponding xib file?

Comment: That property should be declared as `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;`. Not sure why that would relate to not being able to load nib though.

Comment: From the name of the nib file, it looks like you're loading the view controller from a storyboard, and that the controller is unable to load its view from the storyboard. If that's the case, you'll need to correct the problem in the storyboard itself rather than in your code.

Comment: Yes, I only have the storyboard. I can't see NIB files. I only have a default LaunchScreen.xib.
In the storyboard I have dragged a tab bar controller that has two items by default. I set the custom class of one of these items to be the class that I have created (the one that crashes) and then embedded the item in a navigation controller.
I don't understand what is 'Mrk-WH-vzE-view-zyB-06-j66'...what sort of name is that?
I changed the declaration of the property like pasta12 suggested but still no success

Comment: It might actually be crashing just before the line about the `items` array. Double-check names of files, classes, and identifiers in your storyboard for typos & inconsistencies. Could be you used a name like `secondController` in one place but `Secondcontroller` in another, so there's a conflict & it can't find/load the right NIB (which is what the error tells you).

Comment: I cannot spot differences. In the storyboard I assigned the custom class to the item by using the inspector, the class was present in the dropdown.
If I comment that line of code, there is no crash :-(

Comment: Can you give us some context for that line? What happens before and after?

Comment: I have added some relevant info in the question

Comment: Can you show your table view delegates? Like `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `numberOfRowsInSection`? Though a crash log would be more helpful.

Comment: Added stack trace and other info required

Answer (score 0):

I have another update. Today I changed computer so downloaded xcode again and tried to run the project....it works...I don't understand why, has there been a new Xcode release in these days?

Answer (score -2):

Change:

`self.items = [NSMutableArray array];`

to

`self.items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

Comment: What effect does that have?

Comment: @Sara is trying to create an `NSMutableArray`, but `NSMutableArray` has no method `array`. So it throws an exception.

Comment: And `NSMutableArray` doesn't subclass another class that does have an `array` class method, perhaps?

Comment: This is not the issue. `+[NSMutableArray array]` overrides `+[NSArray array]` to return a mutable array, though this is not mentioned in the `NSMutableArray` documentation. Further, the pasted error does not reflect what you've suggested.

Comment: Doh! Sorry about that. I wasn't even thinking of subclasses. That will teach me to answer questions when I have a head cold. :(

Thanks for correcting me @Droppy.

Comment: Did the change suggested by Larry but nothing changed.

Comment: @SaraCle If you are getting crashes then you must upload the stacktrace and relevant code.  There are thousands of potential reasons for a crash.

Comment: I have added some relevant info in the question